# Javascript exact substring

Tags: javascript, console.log, substring

How do I print out the substring for `"Melbourne is"` from `"Melbourne is great"`? (Note the space),using console.log ?

Comment: Do you mean just: `"Melbourne is great".substr(0, 12)` or do you need some logic? Like: find the 2nd space and cut there?

Comment: I meant the latter, find the space and cut there, thanks a lot  buddy, already got a solution, just joined stack overflow, great community.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the last part of a string you could split it to an array. Then remove the last element in it, and then join it back to a string again:

```
var str = "Melbourne is Great";
var temp = str.split(' ');
temp.pop(); // remove last element
var out = temp.join(' '); // "Melbourne is"
```

Alternative if you want to keep remove everything after the 2. space you could find the index of that space. Then make a substring with that index:

```
var str = "Melbourne is Great";
// String.prototype.indexOf(needle[, offset]);
var index = str.indexOf(' ', str.indexOf(' ')+1);
var out = str.slice(0, index);
```

If you want to keep everything before "Great" you could use the same approach as above.

You could also use a temp array:

```
var str = "Melbourne is Great";
var temp = str.split(' ');
// Make a new array that contains the first to elements from temp, then join it on space.
var out = temp.slice(0, 2).join(' ');
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different ways to handle this:

1. If you know that you want to remove the last word, you can cut from the last space using [`substr`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) and [`lastIndexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf):

   ```
   var str = 'Melbourne is great';
   return str.substr(0, str.lastIndexOf(' '));
   ```
2. If you know that you want the first two words, you can use a regex [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) to match part of the phrase and return that section:

   ```
   var str = 'Melbourne is great';
   return str.replace(/([^ ]+ [^ ]+).*/, '$1');
   ```
3. If you want to get a certain number of leading (or trailing) words, you can break the string down into word tokens using [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice):

   ```
   var str = 'Melbourne is great';
   return str.split(' ').slice(0, 2)
   ```

There are a lot of potential ways to handle string manipulation in almost any language and the best option really depends on your exact use case.

For more reference, you should take a look at [MDN's `String` page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String), which lists all of the methods available on a string object.

Comment: Any reason not to use `.slice` for strings as well? I mean it's the most diverse method.

Comment: Btw the 2. method will not work for strings with newline matches by `.*`: `'Melbourne is gr\neat'.replace(/([^ ]+ [^ ]+).*/, '$1'); // "Melbourne is\neat"`

Comment: Hey, super helpful, forgot to mention, print out the substring for "Melbourne is" via console.log